# Is it possible to convert datetime field to date field for date comparison? (Odoo 13)

Tags: date, datetime, comparison, odoo-13

Suppose I have two models.

model_a.py with 2 fields:

```
  name = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee name')
  start_datetime = fields.Datetime('Datetime working')
```

I created 4 records based on that fields. And the results in display user Tree View like this:

```
 Employee name     Datetime working
 A                 10/26/2021 07:00:00
 B                 10/26/2021 08:00:00
 C                 10/26/2021 09:00:00
 D                 10/27/2021 07:00:00
```

model_b.py with 1 field:

```
 start_date = fields.Date('Date working')
```

Then I selected on: 10/26/2021 for start_date field.

And I want to load all records on 10/26/2021 without passing a specific time of datetime field in model_a.py via date comparison of:

> @onchange('start_date')

I know that Date fields can only be compared to date objects.

I'd tried to convert like this:

```
 start_datetime = fields.Datetime('Datetime working')
 get_date = start_datetime.date()
```

But I got errors with this:

```
  .....
  [Previous line repeated 317 more times]
  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Note: I still want to keep the format of the Datetime field as 'Datetime'

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I'd solved my requirement.
Using combine and timedelta to add an extra day as two conditions in the domain of @onchange.

In model_b.py:

```
from datetime import timedelta
...
@api.onchange('get_date')
def _get_date(self):
for rec in self:
 if rec.start_date:
   time = datetime.min.time()
   date = rec.get_date
   list_data = self.env['model.a'].search([('start_datetime', '>', datetime.combine(date,time)),
                                           ('start_datetime', '<', date + timedelta(days=1))])
```